# CentOS 7, how to prevent any process from suspending my server?

Tags: linux, centos, suspend

I have a server running CentOS 7 with Gui.
It should be running 24x7 but it keeps suspending itself after a few days of inactivity.

- "Automatic suspend" is already set to "off"
- The computer is only connected to a local network.
- The only third party process I am running is a license server.

I inspected the log, something is asking for a suspend, how can I find what is it?
Or how can I prevent anythings from suspending my server?

suspicous system log:

```
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx dbus-daemon: dbus[684]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service'
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx dbus[684]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service'
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx dbus-daemon: dbus[684]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx dbus[684]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx fprintd: Launching FprintObject
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx fprintd: ** Message: D-Bus service launched with name: net.reactivated.Fprint
Oct 27 22:33:37 xxxx fprintd: ** Message: entering main loop
Oct 27 22:33:39 xxxx NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1572186818.9235] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Oct 27 22:33:39 xxxx NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1572186819.3313] manager: sleeping...
Oct 27 22:33:39 xxxx NetworkManager[739]: <info>  [1572186819.8106] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Oct 27 22:33:40 xxxx dbus-daemon: dbus[684]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Oct 27 22:33:40 xxxx dbus[684]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Oct 27 22:33:40 xxxx systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct 27 22:33:42 xxxx systemd-logind: Delay lock is active (UID 0/root, PID 3029/gnome-shell) but inhibitor timeout is reached.
Oct 27 22:33:42 xxxx dbus-daemon: dbus[684]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 27 22:33:42 xxxx dbus[684]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (4 scripts)
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx systemd: Reached target Sleep.
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx systemd: Starting Sleep.
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx systemd: Starting Suspend...
Oct 27 22:33:43 xxxx systemd-sleep: Suspending system...
Oct 27 22:33:44 xxxx kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.020 seconds) done.
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: serial 00:09: disabled
Oct 28 14:14:33 xxxx kernel: serial 00:09: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

Comment: Why is there a GUI installed on this "server"? It should probably be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your `systemd` [sleep/hibernate services](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.html) configuration. Here is [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.conf.html) how it could be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file, uncomment the lines you want to change from default and replace the variable with `ignore`.

I followed this: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html